# Namespacing something in a custom directory under app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm wanting to create a custom directory under app, and have a corresponding namespace, like:

`app/my_widgets`

and

```
#app/my_widgets/foo
module MyWidgets
  class Foo
     #...
  end
end
```

This doesn't work.

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Foo, expected /project_dir/app/my_widgets/foo.rb to define it.
```

I am calling:

```
MyWidgets::Foo.new()
```

I had guessed this could be because rails autoloads constants from subdirectories of `app/`... However, adding:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W{#{config.root}/app"}
```

Doesn't fix it as I thought it might. Is this a lost cause?

I have tried moving `my_widgets/` to something else, eg 'services/' under app, and then everything works as expected.

Is there any way to have a namespace & corresponding directory directly under `app/`, though?

Comment: How it doesn't work? How do you call class Foo? Like `Foo.new()` or `MyWidgets::Foo.new()`? Because the second option must be correct one.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Sure thing, will edit